# No Ethernet after upgrade to 16.10

Tags: dell, ethernet, 16.10

I have a Dell Inspiron 5315 and was using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit. All was working and I did a update to 16.10 32-bit and I lost the Ethernet connection. I don't have WiFi on the desktop. It has a AMD Athlon64 processor. How do I get the Ethernet working again. Thanks for any help y'all can give.

```
Kernel modules: sata_nv, pata_acpi
00:09.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge [10de:03e8] (rev a2)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:0b.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge [10de:03e9] (rev a2)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration [1022:1100]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map [1022:1101]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller [1022:1102]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control [1022:1103]
    Kernel driver in use: k8temp
    Kernel modules: k8temp
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV516 [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series] [1002:7187]
    Subsystem: Dell RV516 [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series] [1028:0402]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
02:00.1 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV516 [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series] (Secondary) [1002:71a7]
    Subsystem: Dell RV516 [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series] (Secondary) [1028:0403]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: It is one command, not two.

Comment: Kernel driver in use: forcedeth
 Kernel modules: forcedeth
00:08.0 IDE interface [0101]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller [10de:03f6] (rev a2)
 Subsystem: Dell Inspiron 531 [1028:020e]

Comment: Would a repair from the live  work to fix the internet

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue after upgrading to 16.10 from 16.04.

I used the following command to get ethernet working again.

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

Restart the PC after running the command.

Check the following thread for more info:

[After upgrade to 16.10 ethernet stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865945/after-upgrade-to-16-10-ethernet-stopped-working)

Comment: I appreciate your help it worked. I hope your knowledge can help others