# Kubuntu no internet connection after upgrading to 16.4

Tags: networking, upgrade, kubuntu, internet

I was upgrading my Kubuntu to 16.04, including Nvidia drivers update. It all was a one big mess. I recovered from most of the issues as aftermath of the process (like UI disappearance etc.). And now I have no internet connection.
What I tried to do:

```
ifconfig -a
```

Gave me this:

```
enp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:8d:5c:7c:9f:ac  
          inet addr:192.168.1.107  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::428d:5cff:fe7c:9fac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:131 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:347 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15165 (15.1 KB)  TX bytes:31123 (31.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:49 (49.0 B)  TX bytes:49 (49.0 B)
```

I opened then etc/network/interfaces ,as was suggested by some other answers on this topic, and added there the 'enp6s0' like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inte loopback

auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet dhcp
```

Then rebooted, and now I can't even see a name of the ethernet connection in the network connection menu at all. Being Linux amateur I am pretty lost.

UPDATE:

Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865945/after-upgrade-to-16-10-ethernet-stopped-working) now I can see again the connection, but no internet though.

UPDATE1:

Well,[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622470/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error-in-ubuntu-14-04#) was my problem, and the answer to the question also has solved my issued.

Comment: post here what you have when you type this: _cat /etc/resolv.conf_. Maybe DNS issue, since you nic is working properly.

Comment: @Redbob nameserver 192.168.0.1 which is my external IP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DNS\_PROBE\_FINISHED\_BAD\_CONFIG error in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622470/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error-in-ubuntu-14-04)